# Imports not working with typescript reducer in redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, local-storage

I am trying to use redux with typescript and have the state saved to local storage but I am having some difficulty having the state saved this is my current code. I am new to type script does anyone have any suggestions

reducers

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import user from "./user";
import account from "./account";
const allReducers = combineReducers({
  user:user
account:account
});


export  type RootState = ReturnType<typeof allReducers>
```

store.js

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import {RootState} from '../reducers/index'

function saveToLocalStorage(state) {
  try {
    const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);
    localStorage.setItem("state", serializedState);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

function loadFromLocalStorage() {
  try {
    const serializedState = localStorage.getItem("state");

    if (serializedState == null) {
      return undefined;
    }

    return JSON.parse(serializedState);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return undefined;
  }
}

const savedState = loadFromLocalStorage();

const store = createStore(
  RootState,
  savedState,
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

store.subscribe(() => saveToLocalStorage(store.getState()));

export default store;
```

I keep on getting this error when I try to compile the code.

```
Attempted import error: 'RootState' is not exported from '../reducers/index'.
```

Comment: Aren't you actually intending to `export const allReducers` and use that in `createStore`? Rather than passing the `type` of `allReducers`?

Comment: I am not actually sure im quite new to typescript and tried to use typescript for the store how should I write it

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with redux, however by reading [the documentation of `createStore`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/other-exports#createstore), I've found:

> ## createStore​
>
> Redux's createStore. You should not need to use this directly.

When looking at the arguments for `createStore`, [this documentation](https://redux.js.org/api/createstore) says that the first argument should be a
[reducing function](https://redux.js.org/understanding/thinking-in-redux/glossary#reducer), while here you're passing an exported typescript type and not an actually callable function.
This leads me to believe that you're using `createStore` incorrectly, which would explain your error: `Attempted import error: 'RootState' is not exported from '../reducers/index'.`

I would start from the [Typescript Quick Start](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/typescript-quick-start#define-root-state-and-dispatch-types) and use the `configureStore` as they suggest to setup the `RootState`.

Also see:

- [Definte Root State and Dispatch Types](https://redux.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#define-root-state-and-dispatch-types)
- [ConfigureStore](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#configurestore)

A slightly different and more advanced usage (should you need it) can be found on [React & Redux in TypeScript - Complete Guide](https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide): [Store Configuration](https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide#store-configuration), but I would still start with the basic tutorial and work from there.